# Gitlab connection to GCP Workload Identity returning invalid_grant on a JWKs parsing error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, workload-identity

I have set up a Workload Identity Federation with an on-premise gitlab installation, the provider status shows as "Enabled" and healthy in the console.

The part I don't get past is specifically this:

```
  - |
    PAYLOAD=$(cat <<EOF
    {
    "audience": "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/${PROJECT_NUMBER}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/${POOL_ID}/providers/${PROVIDER_ID}",
    "grantType": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange",
    "requestedTokenType": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "subjectTokenType": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt",
    "subjectToken": "${CI_JOB_JWT_V2}"
    }
    EOF
    )
  - echo $PAYLOAD
  - |
    FEDERATED_TOKEN=$(curl -X POST "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token"
    --header "Accept: application/json"
    --header "Content-Type: application/json"
    --data "${PAYLOAD}"
    )
  - echo $FEDERATED_TOKEN
```

Compared to the [Gitlab Working Example](https://gitlab.com/guided-explorations/gcp/configure-openid-connect-in-gcp/-/blob/main/run_gcp_sts.sh#L3-14) this seems correct enough, if I change the audience I get errors on that my audience value is incorrect so it seems to at least talk to the server.

This is the error response for `FEDERATED_TOKEN`:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Parsing error for JWKs: [Line 0, column 0: Unexpected end of stream : expected '{']"}
```

I've tried googling around for the `Parsing error for JWKs` but haven't learned anything useful, does anyone have any guidance?

Thanks in advance!

#### Update after comments from before June 20th

Adding or removing `--header "Accept: application/json"` did not do much. The `subjectToken` seems to be correct:

Header part:

```
{"alg":"RS256","kid":"[REDACTED]","typ":"JWT"}
```

Payload part:

```
{"namespace_id":"46","namespace_path":"devops","project_id":"682","project_path":"devops/terraform-source","user_id":"REDACTED","user_login":"chase","user_email":"REDACTED","pipeline_id":"124241","pipeline_source":"push","job_id":"1131468","ref":"workload-identity-debugging","ref_type":"branch","ref_protected":"false","jti":"REDACTED-1d58-43f6-9b92-72914b937023","iss":"REDACTED","iat":REDACTED,"nbf":REDACTED,"exp":REDACTED,"sub":"project_path:devops/terraform-source:ref_type:branch:ref:workload-identity-debugging","aud":"REDACTED"}
```

The signature is hard to decrypt/debug.

The header, payload and signature are formatted in base64 and as expted concatted together using `.` (dots).

##### gcloud

Another interesting behavior I noticed when trying to grab an access token using `gcloud` directly:

```
$ echo ${CI_JOB_JWT_V2} > .ci_job_jwt_file
$ gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config "projects/REDACTED/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/${POOL_ID}/providers/${PROVIDER_ID}" --service-account="${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL}" --output-file=.gcp_temp_cred.json --credential-source-file=.ci_job_jwt_file
Created credential configuration file [.gcp_temp_cred.json].
$ gcloud auth login --cred-file=`pwd`/.gcp_temp_cred.json
Authenticated with external account credentials for: [terraformer@REDACTED.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
Your current project is [None].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
$ gcloud auth list
                    Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       terraformer@REDACTED.iam.gserviceaccount.com
To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
$ echo "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.print-access-token) ("Error code invalid_grant: Parsing error for JWKs: [Line 0, column 0: Unexpected end of stream : expected '{']", '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Parsing error for JWKs: [Line 0, column 0: Unexpected end of stream : expected \'{\']"}')
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=
```

Which seems to be the same thing I'm looking at from sts directly.

Cheers,
Chase

Comment: I've not used Workload Identity Federation. You could try [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) and calling the endpoint from the Secure Token Service's [token](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/sts/rest/v1/TopLevel/token) method there. This may help guide you on what you're `POST`'ing to the endpoint. I suspect (!?) that you're not encapsulating|escaping the `subjectToken` correctly. The error says you're missing a `{` and this is likely the place that it's happening.

Comment: 1) Note you are adding the header **--header "Accept: application/json"** which is wrong. The response is not JSON. 2) My guess is `CI_JOB_JWT_V2` is corrupt or formatted incorrectly. It should be a Base64 encoded JWT (header + payload + signature).

Comment: I updated the OP with some updates/debugging after the comments.

Comment: Adding for future searchers: in my case the error was "There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens:" followed by a generic 500 "Internal error encountered.".  Same root cause of GitLab instance not being accessible from the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out these are symptoms of Google Workload Identity Federation not being able to 1) connect to your issuer (in my case, Gitlab) 2) parse the `jwks_uri`.

From [Verification of external credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-workload-identity-federation#verification_of_external_credentials) we can learn two things:

- there's a connection being made to `$ISSUER/.well-known/openid-configuration` AKA the discovery document (so make sure that is reachable)
- there's a **follow-up** request being made to the value of `jwks_uri` in the discovery document (make sure that is also reachable)

Finally, if your `jwks_uri` is returning a 500 error, [it is discussed here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/-/issues/2041#note_331749635) that you should either add double quotes around the `openid_connect_signing_key` (found in `rails-secret`) or replace the `\n` to multiline.
After restarting my gitlab deployment, I was able to hit the `jwks_uri` (and so was Workload Identity) - after which I was able to generate access tokens.

Problem solved!